# Двоичная система счисления

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать перевод числа из двоичной системы счисления в десятичную, чтобы оно записывалось в виде суммы степеней двоичной системы счисления на соответствующее число в разряде системы.

Что здесь нужно добавить

```
<?php
$i = '101';
function myBin2Dec($i) {
  sum k[i](2^(i)); i = {0; ->} //направление разбора строки с представленным двоичным числом, с права на лево. где i элемент последовательности. k значение iго элемента

  echo "=======\n<br>i = ".i."; base = 10\n</br>=======</br>";
}
$result = myBin2Dec($i);
echo "result = ".$result."\n</br>";
?>
```

Comment: sum k[i]*(2^(i)); i = {0; ->} направление разбора строки с представленным двоичным числом, с права на лево. где i элемент последовательности. k значение iго элемента. пример 1101 <-; 1*(2^0) + 0 * (2^1) + 1*(2^2) + 1*(2^3) = 1 + 4 + 8 = 13

Comment: А как мне в скрипте это записать?

Comment: Что здесь нужно добавить

    <?php
    $i = '101';
    function myBin2Dec($i) {
      sum k[i](2^(i)); i = {0; ->} //направление разбора строки с представленным двоичным числом, с права на лево. где i элемент последовательности. k значение iго элемента 
     
      echo "=======\n<br>i = ".i."; base = 10\n</br>=======</br>";
    }
    $result = myBin2Dec($i);
    echo "result = ".$result."\n</br>";
    ?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так, без особых проверок...

```
<?php
$input = '1101';

function bin2dec($data)
{
  $result_dbg = "";
  $result = 0;
  $dataLen = strlen($data);

  for($i = 0, $sh = $dataLen; $i < $dataLen; $i++, $sh--){
    $elem = (int) substr($data, $sh - 1, 1);
    $result_dbg .= "$elem*(2^$i)  "; 
    $result += $elem * pow(2, $i);
  }
  $result_dbg .=" = $result";
  print (  $result_dbg );
  return $result;
}

bin2dec($input);

?>
```

результат: 1*(2^0) 0*(2^1) 1*(2^2) 1*(2^3) = 13